# spring saml Cannot sign outgoing message as no signing credential is set in the context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, saml-2.0

I'm trying to use the standard [spring saml example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml) with locally stored SP meta data. After verifying that the example works fine with the auto-generated meta-data, I stored the data locally using the provided instructions:

> In order to permanently store the metadata follow these instructions:
>
> - Store metadata content inside your achrive at
>   /WEB-INF/classes/metadata/vcdevelopmenttestrobert_sp.xml
> - Make sure to update your identity provider(s) with the generated metadata
> - Modify bean "metadata" in your securityContext.xml and include content from
>   the configuration above

I get the error (while triggering the SSO login)

```
Message:
Cannot sign outgoing message as no signing credential is set in the context 

StackTrace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot sign outgoing message as no signing credential is set in the context
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.sendMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:222)
at ...
```

the meta-data looks like this:

```
 <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.lang.String">http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="int">5000</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="/metadata/vcdevelopmenttestrobert_sp.xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="local" value="true"/>
                        <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                        <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
                        <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
                        <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
                        <property name="signingKey" value="null"/>
                        <property name="encryptionKey" value="null"/>
                        <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="true"/>
                        <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="true"/>
                        <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryURL" value="http://localhost:8080/saml/discovery"/>
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL" value="http://localhost:8080/saml/login?disco=true"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean> 
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
 </bean>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: the signingKey and encryptionKey should be changed to:

```
  <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
  <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
```

I found the answer [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-sp-import). It would be nice if the meta-data admin page would have a hint on this.